# Copy an Image from Flex Application (Web) and paste it outside the application

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5

I have a requirement that we should be able to copy an image displayed in our application, to Clipboard and paste it outside (Like on Excel).

I was trying the below code snippet (Inside a button Click).

> Clipboard.generalClipboard.clear();
>                     var dataLoaded:Boolean = Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.RICH_TEXT_FORMAT,
>   byteArray, false);

The dataLoaded object is true, however it does not paste anything when tried on Excel or MsPaint.

Do we have any way to achieve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The code you are showing is not enough in itself to get a successful transfer. Like many other operations within the security sandbox of a FP app (web) this code can only respond to a direct user interaction. So your code without any valid context cannot work of course but if called within a mouse down listener for example (a true user generated mouse event, creating a fake mouseevent would still not work) it should respond correctly:

```
private function handleMouseClick(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    Clipboard.generalClipboard.clear(); 
    var dataLoaded:Boolean = Clipboard.generalClipboard.setData(ClipboardFormats.RICH_TEXT_FORMAT, byteArray, false);
}
```

Comment: I did enter the above code inside a button click, like you have mentioned.

Comment: Updated the description to reflect the same.